# Design of model of player in a simple game with computer and human players

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

Let's say I have a simple game, in which player can choose object X. Human can obviously do it via gui, and computer via some strategy. They both share same model class, Player:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private X x;

    public Player(name, x) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice no setters, which means that every time they make a choice I have to create a new object of Player, with same name but different X.

Now, this strategy is an interface,

```
public interface PlayerXChoiceStrategy {
    public X getPlayersChoice();
}
```

and there are for example two classes implementing this, `HumanXChoiceStrategy` and `SomeBotXChoiceStrategy`. I don't want to have these strategies in model and I don't want to use something like `Map<Player, PlayerXChoiceStrategy>` because Player is immutable, so that would create some problems. How can I possibly retrieve the strategy in a fast manner and not rely on model/map? I obviously use these strategies in lets say a Controller class where I call every players `getPlayersChoice()`.

My only idea is to have a `Map<String name, PlayerXChoiceStrategy>` and I'll probably implement unless someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: If you're relying on very fast lookup, you're going to be pulled towards a `Map`, because it's the fastest structure in terms of runtime complexity.

Comment: Yeah I do realize that, is there any other way that is not quite as fast but still viable? I was trying to think of some design pattern but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: What's about some class like `Game`? Then you will able to put right there your Strategies and associate them with your players. Probably it's useful to use `Pair<T1, T2>` - in your case it will be `Pair<Player, Strategy>`

Comment: There is class game, but mapping isn't ideal because whenever players X change I have to create new Instance of it, so I would have to do: `Strategy strategy = strategyByPlayer.get(Player);` then `strategyByPlayer.remove(Player)` and finally `strategyByPlayer.put(<player with new weapon>, strategy)` which isn't the most clean solution, with mutable objects it would be even worse

Comment: Just curious as to why String as a key is okay but Player is not? Both are immutable right? Also, why do you have to create a new Player object everytime they make a choice? Is your player exploding into multiple players of the same type?

Comment: Player is not because it has two fields: X and name. Whenever X changes I have to create a new player, because he is immutable, and that would require modifying the map, while his name stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Human can obviously do it via gui, and computer via some strategy

Well, this is OOP at its deepest, isn't it? ;)

I would make `Player` class a base class with `getStrategy` abstract method and descend two classes from it: `HumanPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer` with `return new XXXStrategy()` different implementations of it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to rename the method from getStrategy to something more meaningful. Actually, wouldn't it be better to simply not have a getter for the strategy? Instead, player should have a method called applyStrategy that delegates the work to the concrete implementaiton of the strategy? If the purpose of the strategy is to perfrom a task such as move the player or pickup an object, the applyStrategy method could be renamed to move() or pickup(). Subsequently, the calls to these methods would look more meaningful; player.move() or player.pickup()...

Comment: @bot Yep, you are probably right. But without looking at what exactly that not-a-strategy does in the application, I cannot suggest a good name for it ;)

Comment: Fair enough. But of all the names, getStrategy definitely doesn't make sense since you don't want to return a strategy and make someone else do the work. While there can be many right possibilities, getStrategy definitely seems wrong.. what do you think?

Comment: @bot I don't really know. It depends on the game. It can really be a strategy. And you might have several AI players, using different strategies to win a human player.

Comment: This is model class however. Actual data representation of data is the same whether it is human or computer - they both have name and X. One way would be to add a field "xGenerationStrategy" to player class, which at the moment seems like a good idea - for humans this class would be asking UI to provide the choice and for bots to generate it.

Comment: @user3885166 What kind of model is this? If this a model of data, I doubt very much a data model can directly interact with a UI (showing dialogs or whatever)

Comment: It would be a reference to the strategy object but yeah still, I guess map is the best choice